# How would I use a delegate in this scenario?

Tags: c#, delegates

A developer friend of mine tells me that loops are much faster using delegates, and I'd like to benchmark it, but I'm having trouble connecting the dots on how it works.

Consider the following balance calculator.  This basically takes a list of accounts and adds the initial value (starting balance) if it exists to the total credits value if it exist and subtracts the total debits value for each account:

```
    private static IDictionary<string, decimal> CalculateBalances(
        IDictionary<string, decimal> initialValue, 
        IDictionary<string, decimal> credits, 
        IDictionary<string, decimal> debits)
    {
        var r = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        foreach (var key in initialValue.Select(k => k.Key)
            .Concat(credits.Select(k => k.Key))
            .Concat(debits.Select(k => k.Key))
            .Distinct())
        {
            r.Add(key,
                (initialValue.ContainsKey(key) ? initialValue[key] : 0M)
                + (credits.ContainsKey(key) ? credits[key] : 0M)
                - (debits.ContainsKey(key) ? debits[key] : 0M)
                );
        }

        return r;
    }
```

This is *fairly* performant on small to medium account lists, but would using delegates be faster?  And frankly, delegate logic seems to be operating at right angles to my thought processes, because I'm scratching my head how to even write this.

Can anyone offer a way to rewrite this using delegates?

Comment: Delegates are supposed to be faster than what, exactly? You're already using delegates for your lambdas (even if you didn't explicitly create them, they're there). What part of your loop would your friend have you replace with delegates, exactly?

Comment: The way she was talking about it, basically replacing all the stuff on the inside of the loop with some delegate call.  I managed to raise a skeptical eyebrow like I knew what she was talking about.

Comment: "delegate logic seems to be operating at right angles to my thought processes" do a toy project in a functional programming language (say, F#), and that "vector of thought" is sure to turn in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your friend is referring to something like the `ForEach` method on the `List<T>` class. The short answer to your question is **no**.

The equivalent syntax would be:

```
initialValue.Select(k => k.Key)
            .Concat(credits.Select(k => k.Key))
            .Concat(debits.Select(k => k.Key))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(var => r.Add(key,
                (initialValue.ContainsKey(key) ? initialValue[key] : 0M)
                + (credits.ContainsKey(key) ? credits[key] : 0M)
                - (debits.ContainsKey(key) ? debits[key] : 0M)
                ));
```

This is *in no way* better than the way you have it above. It is both slower and more difficult to read. Delegate invocation is slower than ordinary method invocation. The syntax you have above is both faster and easier to read.

Comment: Hmm.  Then in what circumstances would the `ForEach` method be attractive on the `List` object?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I can't think of a circumstance where it would be *better*.

Comment: When I get the lists built, I'll try to remember to post the benchmarks here.  It should be interesting to see.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone offer a way to rewrite this using delegates?

But you *are* using delegates already! That's what the lambdas are being converted to. 
The question about whether to use a delegate or not for the loop-body for performance reasons is a little strange when so many delegate invocations are being used just to produce each item of the sequence.

Anyway, Adam Robinson has already covered how you would `List.ForEach` to execute a side-effect on each item of a list and the associated readability and performance implications, so I won't go into that.

But here's how I would write your method if the marginal overhead of LINQ and delegate invocations were not a deciding factor:

```
return initialValue
       .Concat(credits)
       .Concat(debits.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>(kvp.Key, -kvp.Value)))
       .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
       .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum());
```

Now that's much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` construct is the right one if you want to build a new dictionary using `Dictionary.Add`. You can always just select from the existing dictionary to create a new one, but that will be slower.

However, as to readability, isn't this much easier?

```
private static decimal GetOrZero(this IDictionary<string,decimal> dict, string key)
{
    decimal value = 0;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value;
}

private static IDictionary<string, decimal> CalculateBalances(
    IDictionary<string, decimal> initialValue, 
    IDictionary<string, decimal> credits, 
    IDictionary<string, decimal> debits)
{   
    var r = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    var accounts = initialValue.Keys.Union(debits.Keys).Union(credits.Keys);

    foreach (var accounts in accounts)
    {
        r.Add(initialValue.GetOrZero(key) + credits.GetOrZero(key) - debits.GetOrZero(key));
    }

    return r;
}
```